# iOS app crash while send msg by socket

Tags: ios, sockets

I use this method for send msg to server

```
ssize_t send(int, const void *, size_t, int) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(send);
```

This is standard Lib from Apple (socket.h and socket.m )

```
NSString *msg = @"Message want to send";
// socketFileDescriptor is int

NSData *wdata = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
ssize_t n;
const UInt8 *buf = (const UInt8 *)[wdata bytes];
n = send(socketFileDescriptor, buf,[wdata length],0); // I really sure,it's crash at this statement on device iPad Air, iPad Air2 only
```

BUT on debug mode isn't not crash!
App will crash when I archive project to IPA (Ad-Hoc Mode)

I have no ideal for this case please help me.

This is more information
I use this method for connect to server
I have already assign value for self.host and self.port variable.
 (I sure it can be connect normally in debug mode)

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KFKJsJHZ

and I use this method for send message to server
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z7Js2JT8

2 method in same class BSDSocket

Please tell me If you want more information.
Thank you

Comment: Posting the callstack of the crash will help figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you post the complete code contains creating and connection of the socket ?

Comment: Have you disabled `SIGPIPE`? You can it if you write to a closed socket.

Comment: I use this method for connect to server  (I sure it can be connect normally in debug mode)


http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KFKJsJHZ



and I use this method for send msg to server
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z7Js2JT8

2 method in same class BSDSocket

Please tell me If you want more information.
Thank you

Comment: I use this method for connect to server
I have already assign value for self.host and self.port variable.
 (I sure it can be connect normally in debug mode)

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KFKJsJHZ

and I use this method for send message to server
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z7Js2JT8

2 method in same class BSDSocket

Please tell me If you want more information.
Thank you